# computing APY and using another method in java

Tags: java, methods

I cant seem to make it work. 
i am trying to get the result of APY and Loanpayment from the main method

I keep getting message that compoundingOption symbol cant be be found. Can anyone detect an error here?

```
public class Finance {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // Practice myPractice = new Practice();
        System.out.println(computeApy(5.50, 1));
        System.out.println(computeLoanPayment(20000.00, 7.5, 15.0, 1));
    }

    public static double computeApy(double annualRate, int compoundingOption) {
        // APY = (1 + (r/n))^n - 1

        // daily
        if (compoundingOption == 1) {
            return (Math.pow((1 + (annualRate / 365)), 365)) - 1;
            // monthly
        }
        else if (compoudingOption == 2) {
            return (Math.pow((1 + (annualRate / 12)), 12)) - 1;
            // annually
        }
        else if (compoudingOption == 3) {
            return (Math.pow((1 + (annualRate / 1)), 1)) - 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static double computeLoanPayment(double principal, double annualRate, double yearsDuration,
        int paymentOption) {
        // A = P * r(1+r)^n / (1+r)^n - 1
        // biweekly
        if (paymentOption == 1) {
            return principal * (annualRate * Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 26)) / ((Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 26)) - 1);
            // monthly
        }
        else if (paymentOption == 2) {
            return principal * (annualRate * Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 12)) / ((Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 12)) - 1);
            // quarterly
        }
        else if (paymentOption == 3) {
            return principal * (annualRate * Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 4)) / ((Math.pow((1 + annualRate), 4)) - 1);
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

compoudingOption  you misspelled in second and third blocks

missing 'n'

You have compoudingOption and variable is compoundingOption